# MS Word macro, how to adapt so it get data from my Excel file?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My project is to change words/phrases in the whole Bible, and I have the Word doc with the Bible in it, and separately, I have an Excel file with Column A oldwords that need to be found by the macro, Column B newwords that will replace the old ones.

I was gracefully provided with this macro, which works well in MS Word 2010, but as you can see, it is setup to use Data arrays. It even says, "'Note: Data arrays are used in this example.  In practice the data could come from a Word table, Excel worksheet or other data source.". So, I need to adapt it so that it gets the data from my Excel file where I have all the words/phrases that need to be changed.

There are 2 class modules and 1 standard module. But at the end of this post, I'm also including yet more code that should do what I want (get data from an Excel file) but it needs to be adapted to work in my macro. The problem is, I don't know how to adapt it. In other words: I don't know what needs to be replaced in the module/s in order to make it work.

Also, I believe my Excel file needs to be simple. Column A Old wordorphrase // Column B New wordorphrase. Would that work fine just like that?

Here is everything I have (separately):

First class module I was told to name it "clsTerm" and paste this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private English                 As String
Private Hebrew                  As String
Private FNT                     As String

Property Let EnglishTerm(strVal As String)
    English = strVal
End Property

Property Get EnglishTerm() As String
    EnglishTerm = English
End Property

Property Let HebrewTerm(strVal As String)
    Hebrew = strVal
End Property

Property Get HebrewTerm() As String
    HebrewTerm = Hebrew
End Property

Property Let FootnoteText(strVal As String)
    FNT = strVal
End Property

Property Get FootnoteText() As String
    FootnoteText = FNT
End Property
```

Second class module I was told to name it "clsTerms" and paste this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private colTerms                As Collection
Private lngCount                As Long

Property Get Items() As Collection
    Set Items = colTerms
End Property

Property Set Items(oCol As Collection)
    Set colTerms = oCol
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    If Not colTerms Is Nothing Then
        Count = colTerms.Count
    Else
        Count = 0
    End If
End Property
```

Then I was told to create a standard module and name it "Anything I like" and paste this code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim m_oCol1                     As Collection
Dim m_oCol2                     As Collection

Sub ReplaceWordsAndDefineFootnotes()
    Dim clsTL                   As clsTerms
    Dim lngIndex                As Long

    Set clsTL = New clsTerms
    Set clsTL.Items = DefinedTerms
    Set m_oCol1 = New Collection
    For lngIndex = 1 To clsTL.Count
        'Replace each defined English word with it Hebrew equivelent.
        ReplaceWords clsTL.Items(lngIndex).EnglishTerm, clsTL.Items(lngIndex).HebrewTerm
    Next lngIndex
    Underline_And_DefineFootnote
    For lngIndex = 1 To clsTL.Count
        'Replace temporary footnote text with with class defined footnote text.
        FixFootnotes clsTL.Items(lngIndex).HebrewTerm, clsTL.Items(lngIndex).FootnoteText
    Next lngIndex
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Function DefinedTerms() As Collection
    Dim arrEng()                As String
    Dim arrHeb()                As String
    Dim lngIndex                As Long
    Dim oCol                    As Collection
    Dim Term                    As clsTerm

    'Note: Data arrays are used in this example.  In practice the data could come from a Word table, Excel worksheet or other data source.
    arrEng = Split("God,heaven,earth,waters,good", ",")
    arrHeb = Split("Elohim,shamayim,aretz,mayim,tov", ",")

    Set oCol = New Collection
    'Put data in the collection.
    For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(arrEng)
        Set Term = New clsTerm
        Term.EnglishTerm = arrEng(lngIndex)
        Term.HebrewTerm = arrHeb(lngIndex)
        Term.FootnoteText = arrEng(lngIndex) & ":" & arrHeb(lngIndex)
        oCol.Add Term, Term.EnglishTerm
    Next lngIndex
    Set DefinedTerms = oCol
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Sub ReplaceWords(ByVal strFind As String, ByVal strReplaceWith As String)
    Dim oRng                    As Word.Range
    'Add each term processed to a collection.
    m_oCol1.Add UCase(strReplaceWith), UCase(strReplaceWith)
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    'Replace each instance of the English word with its Hebrew equivalent.
    With oRng.Find
        .Text = strFind
        .Replacement.Text = strReplaceWith
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub Underline_And_DefineFootnote()
    Dim oRng                    As Word.Range
    Dim lngIndex                As Long
    Dim oWord                   As Word.Range
    Dim strWord                 As String
    Dim lngCounter              As Long
    Dim lngPages                As Long

    With ActiveDocument
        Set oRng = .Range
        lngPages = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
        For lngIndex = 1 To lngPages
Reprocess:
            Set m_oCol2 = New Collection
            Set oRng = oRng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=lngIndex)
            Set oRng = oRng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
            lngCounter = 1
            With oRng
                For Each oWord In oRng.Words
                    'Modify the word range to strip off white space.  We want only the text portion of the word range.
                    strWord = UCase(Trim(oWord.Text))
                    oWord.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                    oWord.MoveEnd wdCharacter, Len(strWord)
                    If oWord.Characters.Last = Chr(160) Then oWord.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                    'We need to know if the text defined by the word range is a word we want to process.
                    'We added all of those words to a collection during the find and replace process.
                    'If we try to add one of those words to the collection again then it will error and we will know _
                     we are dealing with a word we want to process.
                    On Error Resume Next
                    m_oCol1.Add strWord, strWord
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        On Error Resume Next
                        'We only want to underline and footnote the first instance of the term on each page.
                        'So add the term and key to a collection.
                        m_oCol2.Add strWord, strWord
                        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                            'There was no error so underline the term and footnote it.
                            oWord.Font.Underline = 1
                            On Error GoTo 0
                            ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add oWord, CStr(lngCounter), LCase(strWord)
                            lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        'The word wasn't a word we want to process so remove it from the collection.
                        m_oCol1.Remove m_oCol1.Count
                    End If
                Next oWord
            End With
            'Since processing words will add footnotes, the length of the document will increase.
            'I'm using this method to reenter the processing loop.
            lngPages = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
            If lngIndex < lngPages Then
                lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
                GoTo Reprocess
            End If
        Next lngIndex
    End With
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub

Sub FixFootnotes(ByVal strFind As String, ByVal strReplaceWith As String)
    Dim oRng                    As Word.Range
    m_oCol1.Add UCase(strReplaceWith), UCase(strReplaceWith)
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory)
    With oRng.Find
        .Text = strFind
        .Replacement.Text = strReplaceWith
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False    'True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

And finally, this is the code that I need to adapt into my macro, in order to make it get the data from the Excel file:

```
Sub ListFromExcel()
Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim arrWords As Variant
'Find words in column 1, Replace words in column 2
arrWords = GetListArray(You file path and name)
For lngIndex = 2 To UBound(arrWords, 1)
  Debug.Print arrWords(lngIndex, 1)
  Debug.Print arrWords(lngIndex, 2)
Next
End Sub

Function GetListArray(ByRef strFileName As String) As Variant
Dim xlapp As Object
Dim xlbook As Object
Dim xlsheet As Object
Dim bAppStart As Boolean
  On Error Resume Next
  Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  If Err Then
    bAppStart = True
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strFileName)
  Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1)
  GetListArray = xlsheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
  xlbook.Close
  If bAppStart = True Then xlapp.Quit
  Set xlapp = Nothing
  Set xlbook = Nothing
  Set xlsheet = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first sub to this

```
Sub ReplaceWordsAndDefineFootnotes()
    Dim clsTL                   As clsTerms
    Dim lngIndex                As Long

    Set clsTL = New clsTerms
    clsTL.FillFromExcel
    Set m_oCol1 = New Collection
    For lngIndex = 1 To clsTL.Count
        'Replace each defined English word with it Hebrew equivelent.
        ReplaceWords clsTL.Items(lngIndex).EnglishTerm, clsTL.Items(lngIndex).HebrewTerm
    Next lngIndex
    Underline_And_DefineFootnote
    For lngIndex = 1 To clsTL.Count
        'Replace temporary footnote text with with class defined footnote text.
        FixFootnotes clsTL.Items(lngIndex).HebrewTerm, clsTL.Items(lngIndex).FootnoteText
    Next lngIndex
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Add this to the clsTerms class

```
Public Sub FillFromExcel()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWb As Object
    Dim vaWords As Variant
    Dim cTerm As clsTerm
    Dim i As Long

    Const sFILE As String = "C:\Users\Dick\Documents\My Dropbox\Excel\wordlist.xlsx"
    Const xlUP As Long = -4162

    Set colTerms = New Collection

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFILE, , True)

    With xlWb.Worksheets(1)
        vaWords = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUP)).Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(vaWords, 1) To UBound(vaWords, 1)
        Set cTerm = New clsTerm
        cTerm.EnglishTerm = vaWords(i, 1)
        cTerm.HebrewTerm = vaWords(i, 2)
        cTerm.FootnoteText = vaWords(i, 1) & ":" & vaWords(i, 2)
        colTerms.Add cTerm
    Next i

    xlWb.Close False
    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question Dick, Is it very difficult to have it let me also find/replace phrases, not just single words? For example, right now it works well to find "God" and replace it with "Elohim", but it won't work when I want to find "In the beginning" and replace with "be resheet".

Comment: Yes, it's difficult. Your footnote code goes through the text word-by-word and adds footnotes. It really needs to go the other way - from the list of words to the text - possibly just adding footnotes as it finds and replaces words and phrases. Maybe there's a reason that can't be done, I'm not a Word expert.

Comment: Hi Dick, I've been all over the place trying to get additional text into the footnotes the code already puts, by trying to find/replace, when in reality there's nothing to replace! Well, my code already does that! It's already getting data from Columns A and B. All I need to do is tell it to get the data ALSO from Column C. How do I tell it just that? (please and thank a million, Dick. You're helping me accomplish something great! :)

Comment: Ask a new question and make sure you 1) tag it VBA and 2) link back to this question. I'll answer it there so this doesn't get too cluttered.

Comment: Sure :) thanks. This way someone else may benefit from your answer too!

Comment: Okay, here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146095/modifying-microsoft-word-vba-macro-to-call-additional-text-from-external-file-an